# Are magento commerce modules worth it?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento-community, magento-2-commerce

I was just evaluating whether it's worth shifting to Magento commerce solely to use their pre-built modules. I don't want to look at their site documentation because they have an obvious bias, so I'm looking for objective insights on why its better. Also, if anyone could give me a few sources to approximate how many people are migrating and why, that would be great. Thanks!